# Previously set DateTime objects not getting value update when using toUtc()

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a method called "showLotteryInfo" that uses some datetime objects. After setting the values using some logic, when I do a .toUtc call on them, the values are not getting updated. Can someone help me understand why ?

```
void showLotteryInfo() {

//DateTime now = new DateTime.now();
DateTime nextLotteryDate = new DateTime.now();
DateTime startingLotteryDate = new DateTime.now();

if (DateTime.now().day < 15){
  nextLotteryDate = DateTime(DateTime.now().year, DateTime.now().month, 15);
  startingLotteryDate =  DateTime(DateTime.now().year, DateTime.now().month, 1); 
}else{
   nextLotteryDate =  DateTime(DateTime.now().year, DateTime.now().month+1, 1);
   startingLotteryDate =  DateTime(DateTime.now().year, DateTime.now().month, 15); 
}


DateTime nextLotteryDateUTC = nextLotteryDate.add(Duration(days: 50)); //this updates the datetime value
DateTime startingLotteryDateUTC = startingLotteryDate.toUtc(); //this DOES not update the datetime value

String endingFormattedDate = DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd').format(nextLotteryDateUTC);
String startingFormattedDate = DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd').format(startingLotteryDateUTC);


showDialog(
  context: context,
  builder: (BuildContext context) {
    return AlertDialog(
      title: const Text("Lottery Info"),
      //content: Text("Next Drawing Date: Lottery Info"),
      content: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        //position
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        // wrap content in flutter
        children: <Widget>[
          Text(
            "Starting Date Range:",
            style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
          ),
          Text(startingFormattedDate),
          Text(
            "Next Drawing Date:",
            style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
          ),
          Text(endingFormattedDate)
        ],
      ),

      actions: <Widget>[
        new TextButton(
          child: const Text("OK"),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.of(context).pop();
          },
        ),
      ],
    );
  },
);
```

}

I'm using Android Studio with an Pixel 5 API 31 emulator

Comment: What do you mean by "the values are not getting updated"?  Can you be more specific?  Are you aware that `.toUtc()` returns a new `DateTime` object and does not mutate an existing object?

Comment: I am not aware. Thank you for the info. That helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
DateTime startingLotteryDateUTC = 
TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(startingLotteryDate, TimeZoneInfo.Local);
```

Or:

```
DateTime startingLotteryDateUTC = DateTime.UtcNow
```

Comment: I get an error when trying the first solution above. Do I need to import some type of dependency or something?

Comment: What error are you getting?